# Install Pygtk on Amazon EC2

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, yum

I want install PywebkitGTK on AWS

**(Amazon EC2, Amazon Linux AMI 2013.09.2(64-bit))**

```
$ sudo ./configure --prefix=/usr
    ...
    checking if libtool supports shared libraries... yes
    checking whether to build shared libraries... yes
    checking whether to build static libraries... yes
    configure: creating ./config.lt
    config.lt: creating libtool
    checking for a Python interpreter with version >= 2.4... python
    checking for python... /usr/bin/python
    checking for python version... 2.6
    checking for python platform... linux2
    checking for python script directory... ${prefix}/lib/python2.6/site-packages
    checking for python extension module directory... ${exec_prefix}/lib64/python2.6/site-packages
    checking for headers required to compile python extensions... found
    checking for pkg-config... /usr/bin/pkg-config
    checking pkg-config is at least version 0.9.0... yes
    checking for DEPS... no

    configure: error: Package requirements (libxslt
                  gthread-2.0
                  pygtk-2.0) were not met:

    No package 'libxslt' found
    No package 'gthread-2.0' found
    No package 'pygtk-2.0' found

    Consider adjusting the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable if you
    installed software in a non-standard prefix.

    Alternatively, you may set the environment variables DEPS_CFLAGS
    and DEPS_LIBS to avoid the need to call pkg-config.
    See the pkg-config man page for more details.
```

On my linuxmint, I can use `sudo apt-get install ...`Dependencies,
but I can't search the same packages via `yum`

Any help would be appreciated :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Amazon Linux AMI does not support any GUI related stuff. In fact, its YUM repo does not even have packages that are even remotely related to GUI. Hence you cannot find the missing packages in the YUM repo of Amazon Linux.

Instead, You may want to try an CentOS/Fedora/Ubuntu/RHEL AMI which supports all the GUI related things. Although these are not configured Out-Of-The-Box, but you can certainly configure them manually.